# iterating through dates doesnt display the 31st of the month

Tags: php, date, datetime, for-loop

I have this code to iterate through a month

```
$begin2 = new DateTime( '2017-08-01' );
$end2 = new DateTime( '2017-08-31' );
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin2, $interval, $end2);
foreach ( $period as $i ){  
    echo $i->format("Y-m-d")."<br/>";
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2017-08-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '2017-08-31' );
 for($i = $begin; $begin <= $end; $i->modify('+1 day')){
    echo $i->format("Y-m-d")."<br/>";
 }
```

Im getting the same results for both, it skips the 31st of august, it does work with other months, Im confused and dont know what could be happening.

Comment: Your second example does include the 31st.  Your first example doesn't, because `DatePeriod` stops when the next `DateTime` is greater than *or equal to* the end `DateTime`: to help with that, you can make the end value be later than the desired one in the period e.g. for you the period wants to hit `2017-08-31 00:00:00` (midnight) so use a later date/time like `2017-08-31 00:00:01`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you var_dump $period you see the problem.
Your end is at 31 August at 00:00.

If you set a time later on the day it will output the date.

```
$begin2 = new DateTime( '2017-08-01' );
$end2 = new DateTime( '2017-08-31 12:00' ); //I set the end at noon here. Any time should work except empty or 00:00
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin2, $interval, $end2);
foreach ( $period as $i ){  
    echo $i->format("Y-m-d")."<br/>";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/1n4W4

Comment: Thanks you made me see, what I was doing wrong. thumbsup